# ¿Cómo filtrar datos de una columna en una lista en R, y eliminar las filas con NA?

Tags: r, rstudio

Quisiera saber como puedo filtrar los datos de una columna en una lista en R, sin que se me generen datos NA, he estado usando este código que me han recomendado en una pregunta anterior:

`Filtro <- lapply(X = Mediamovil2010, FUN  = function(x){x[x$"Media movil PM10" > 50,]})`

Sin embargo, parece que deja la misma cantidad de filas en cada elemento de la lista, convirtiendo las que no cumplen, en NA. Quisiera saber si es posible realizar un filtro, que me deje sólo las filas que cumplan con el parámetro establecido, y si no cumple, que me deje el número de filas en 0.

Pido esto, ya que necesito realizar una relación entre listas, que divida el total de datos, sobre los datos que superar cierto límite, comparando los datos de las listas entre sí.

Por otro lado, quisiera saber cómo eliminar los datos NA en toda la lista, ya sea en las filas o en una columna determinada.

Dejo una muestra de **un elemento** de la lista, la lista, está conformado por muchos data.frames como el de acontinuación:

```
$ MOVILING_RochePM10.csv                                :Classes ‘spec_tbl_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':    2191 obs. of  26 variables:
..$ X1                : num [1:2191] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ...
..$ Unnamed: 0        : num [1:2191] 357271 357272 357273 357274 357275 ...
..$ rowid             : num [1:2191] 3083119 3083120 3083121 3083122 3083123 ...
..$ date              : chr [1:2191] "1999-01-01" "1999-01-02" "1999-01-03" "1999-01-04" ...
..$ site              : chr [1:2191] "ROCHE (PM-10)" "ROCHE (PM-10)" "ROCHE (PM-10)" "ROCHE (PM-10)" ...
..$ EnvAut            : chr [1:2191] "CORPOGUAJIRA - CAR DE LA GUAJIRA" "CORPOGUAJIRA - CAR DE LA GUAJIRA" "CORPOGUAJIRA - CAR DE LA GUAJIRA" "CORPOGUAJIRA - CAR DE LA GUAJIRA" ...
..$ Latitude          : num [1:2191] 11.1 11.1 11.1 11.1 11.1 ...
..$ Longitude         : num [1:2191] -72.6 -72.6 -72.6 -72.6 -72.6 ...
..$ AveragingTimeHours: num [1:2191] 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 24 ...
..$ Year              : num [1:2191] 1999 1999 1999 1999 1999 ...
..$ Units             : chr [1:2191] "ugm3" "ugm3" "ugm3" "ugm3" ...
..$ COD_DEP           : num [1:2191] 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 44 ...
..$ NOM_DEP           : chr [1:2191] "La Guajira" "La Guajira" "La Guajira" "La Guajira" ...
..$ COD_MUN           : num [1:2191] 44078 44078 44078 44078 44078 ...
..$ NOM_MUN           : chr [1:2191] "Barrancas" "Barrancas" "Barrancas" "Barrancas" ...
..$ StationType       : chr [1:2191] "Fija" "Fija" "Fija" "Fija" ...
..$ CO                : logi [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ NO                : logi [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ NO2               : logi [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ O3                : logi [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ PM10              : num [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ PM2.5             : num [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ PST               : logi [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ SO2               : logi [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ Media movil PM10  : num [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..$ Media movil PM2.5 : num [1:2191] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
..- attr(*, "spec")=List of 3
.. ..$ cols   :List of 26
.. .. ..$ X1                : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
.. .. ..$ Unnamed: 0        : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
.. .. ..$ rowid             : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
.. .. ..$ date              : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_character" "collector"
.. .. ..$ site              : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_character" "collector"
.. .. ..$ EnvAut            : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_character" "collector"
.. .. ..$ Latitude          : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
.. .. ..$ Longitude         : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
.. .. ..$ AveragingTimeHours: list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
.. .. ..$ Year              : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_number" "collector"
.. .. ..$ Units             : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_character" "collector"
.. .. ..$ COD_DEP           : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
.. .. ..$ NOM_DEP           : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_character" "collector"
.. .. ..$ COD_MUN           : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_double" "collector"
.. .. ..$ NOM_MUN           : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_character" "collector"
.. .. ..$ StationType       : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_character" "collector"
.. .. ..$ CO                : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_logical" "collector"
.. .. ..$ NO                : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_logical" "collector"
.. .. ..$ NO2               : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_logical" "collector"
.. .. ..$ O3                : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_logical" "collector"
.. .. ..$ PM10              : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_number" "collector"
.. .. ..$ PM2.5             : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_number" "collector"
.. .. ..$ PST               : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_logical" "collector"
.. .. ..$ SO2               : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_logical" "collector"
.. .. ..$ Media movil PM10  : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_number" "collector"
.. .. ..$ Media movil PM2.5 : list()
.. .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_number" "collector"
.. ..$ default: list()
.. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "collector_guess" "collector"
.. ..$ skip   : num 1
.. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "col_spec"
```

¡Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede con la función que nos muestras en que en caso de que existan NA dentro de la columna estos nos los filtrara, solo regresara NA tienes que agregar una condicional donde le digas que no quieres que la columna tenga NA por lo que quedaría de esta manera

```
Filtro <- lapply(X = Mediamovil2010, FUN  = function(x){x[x$"Media movil PM10" > 50 | is.na(x$"Media movil PM10")==FALSE,]})
```

Comment: ¡Hola Ruben, muchas gracias por tu respuesta! He colocado el código y me aparece el siguiente mensaje de error `Error: inesperado '}' in "Filtro <- lapply(X = Mediamovil2010, FUN  = function(x){x[x$"Media movil PM10" > 50 | is.na(x$"Media movil PM10")=="FALSE"}"`

Comment: Hola acabo de realizar una modificación ya debería de funcionar correctamente

Comment: Gracias nuevamente Ruben, qué pena contigo, me aparece un nuevo mensaje de error: `Error in "[.data.frame"(x, x$"Media movil PM10" > 50 | is.na(x$"Media movil PM10") == undefined columns selected` 
¡Muchas Gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Listo acabo de realizar otra modificación espero que ahora si funcione Saludos

Comment: Buenas noches Rubén, ya he podido solucionar el problema. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Buenas noches LauraR cual fue la solución ?

Comment: Hola Ruben, utilicé el siguiente código, y eso ha solucionado el problema: lapply(Mediamovil2010, function(x) x[which(x[, "Media movil PM10"]>50),] ) -> salida